# Twitter API 401 when try to get friends list

Tags: python, twitter

I try to obtain list of friends and actually CAN'T use any api, like twitter and OAuth (it's studying task actually)
I successfully do request_token and access_token. But after it i try to get friends/list.json and get 401 (32 we couldn't authorize you)

```
def get_friends(self):
    address = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?" + self.user_id
    params = {
        'oauth_token': self.token,
        'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
        'oauth_nonce': self.get_nonce(),
        'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_version': '1.0',
        'oauth_consumer_key': self.consumer_key
    }
    params['oauth_signature'] = self.get_sign(address, params, 'GET')
    http_request = Request(address)
    http_request.add_header("Authorization", self.get_header(params))
    try:
        received = (urlopen(http_request,
                            bytes('', 'ascii')).read())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.read())
```

def get_sign(self, address, params, method):
    sorted_params = sorted(params.items())
    params_string = ''
    for param in sorted_params:
        params_string += '{}={}&'.format(param[0], param[1])
    params_string = quote(params_string[:-1], '')
    string = method + '&' + quote(address, '') + '&' + params_string
    raw = string.encode()
    decoder = (self.cons_secret + '&').encode()
    hashed = hmac.new(decoder, raw, sha1)
    sign = quote(str(b64encode(hashed.digest()))[2:-1])
    return sign

Answer (score 0):

Verify your OAuth credentials and sometimes even if everything is correct you will get some errors like 'Peer not authenticated' or 'Unauthorised access'. This is because calls to that api version will have endpoints.